# Why do I make "use of deleted" function when passing a std::ofstream as parameter?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a member that is `std::ofstream fBinaryFile` and a

```
void setFile( std::ofstream& pBinaryFile ) 
{
    fBinaryFile = pBinaryFile;
}
```

output:

```
 Data.h:86:16: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>& std::basic_ofstream<char>::operator=(const
 std::basic_ofstream<char>&)’
     fBinaryFile = pBinaryFile;
                 ^
```

I understood that copy in `std::ofstream` is not allowed and maybe I'm missing something. Is possible save the content of `pBinaryFile` in `fBinaryfile`?

Comment: What actually are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to copy `ofstream` to a local variable?

Comment: You can't copy a stream, it's as simple as that. You can only have references (or a pointer) to a stream. What is the original problem you try to solve? What is your use-case?

Comment: You could use a reference or pointer though.

Comment: Or `move` it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Isn't std::ofstream& pBinaryFile pass by reference?  If so, why isn't it fBinaryFile = pBinaryFile allowed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the relevant operator is declared as

```
ofstream& operator= (const ofstream&) = delete;
```

which means it is explicitly prohibited so `ofstream` semantics does to support copying.

Depending on your architecture you can store a pointer/reference or move it.

Comment: in the documentation:
move:
ofstream& operator= (ofstream&& rhs); I can't figure out , still not working. I understand the problem but I can't understand how to move pBinaryFile in fBinaryFile.

Move assignment
Acquires the contents of rhs, by move-assigning its members and base classes.

Comment: Use `std::move` as in `fBinaryFile = std::move(pBinaryFile)`. However make sure you read on move operations and understand what is going on when you do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but this didn't fixed the problem, I read the documentation and I can-t understand what I'm missing, I hope is not a compilation problem, I use g++ -std=c++11 .......

Comment: sorry, what problem are you referring to?

Comment: error: use of deleted function,  I used the function void setFile( std::ofstream& pBinaryFile ) {
   fBinaryFile = std::move(pBinaryFile);  } but error is not solved, around in internet I saw that g++ has some problem with move function.

Comment: what compiler are you using? I just tried in gcc 5.2 it is ok, 4.9.2 fails because its version of stl indeed does not have the move operator=

Comment: I use gcc 4.8.2 on scientific linux, maybe this is the problem, I try to update, thanks for the help

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin thank you so much. switching from gcc 4.8 to 5 resolved the `use of delete` error from compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the content of pBinaryFile to fBinaryFile you need to declare pBinaryfile as an ifstream (input file stream), not an ofstream (output file stream)
It should look something like this:

```
std::ifstream pBinaryFile;
std::ofstream fBinaryFile;
std::stringstream sstream;
std::string line
pBinaryFile.open(pBinaryFileName.c_str());
fBinaryFile.open(fBinaryFileName.c_str());
if (pBinaryFile.isopen()) {
    while (pBinaryFile.good()) {
        getline(pBinaryFile, line);
        fBinaryFile << sstream(line) << endl;
    }
}
pBinaryFile.close();
fBinaryFile.close();
```

Note that pBinaryFileName and fBinaryFileName refer to the paths of your files.

There might be mistakes in this code, but I think the solution looks similar to this.

I suggest this for further reading:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/